# How to declare the type of an object to be any class but not primitive types

Tags: typescript

Is it possible in TypeScript to specify that the type of an object can be any class but not a primitive type.

Something like that but with this restriction:

```
myObj<any>;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, let's see...

Primitives are not recognized as objects with string-keyed properties by the TypeScript compiler, and since an object type will always have `string` keys and `any` values for those keys, the following type definition seems to be adequate:

```
function noPrimitives(a: { [key: string]: any }) {
    // ...
}
```

That is, an object `a` that has string-based keys and `any` values associated with those property keys (primitives don't have string-based property keys as such). The following tests seem to validate my assumptions; properties on numeric, string, and boolean literals are not recognized:

```
noPrimitives(5); // arguments of type 'number' is not assignable [...]
noPrimitives("five"); // arguments of type 'string' is not assignable [...]
noPrimitives(true); // arguments of type 'boolean' is not assignable [...]

noPrimitives(new Number(5)); // ok
noPrimitives(new String("five")); // ok
noPrimitives(new Boolean(true)); // ok
noPrimitives(new Date()); // ok
noPrimitives(null); // ok (typeof null === "object")
```

It also seems to work with types having numeric indexers (presumably because of how Javascript would convert numeric keys to strings anyways):

```
var a: { [key: number]: any };

noPrimitives(a); // ok
noPrimitives(new Array()); // ok
noPrimitives([]); // ok
```

---

> Something like that but with this restriction: `myObj<any>`

This is not actually a restriction, but the effective *disabling* of this restriction, the compile-time type-checking feature. If you happen to need to lift it inside a function or method, just assign to a variable of type `any`:

```
function noPrimitives(a: { [key: string]: any }) {
    var _a: any = a;
    // ...
}
```

If you are not inside a function scope and don't want to create new variables, you'll need to use type assertions (TypeScript equivalent of type-casting) with `any`:

```
var a: { [key: string]: any };

// ...

(a as any).anyMethod();
```

Comment: Actually, you can apply that restriction: `function noPrimitives<T extends { [key: string]: any }>(a:T)`
It will work perfectly with your code and enable generics: `function noPrimitives<T extends { [key: string]: any }>(a:T):T`, `var s = noPrimitives(new String())`

Comment: @zlumer Yes, that's exactly what I'd do, but there's nothing in the question that indicates it's a parameter we are talking about. It can be a simple local variable, or a type member. I was just using a function to demonstrate an example. Anyways, feel free to edit the answer if you'd wish to include that.

Answer (score 5):

TypeScript 2.2 has [introduced](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/02/typescript-22-rc) a new `object` type to represent any non-primitive type:

```
function mapObject(obj: object): object { /* ... */ }
...
mapObject('string'); // type error
```

This should be exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

slightly different than what the poster is asking for, but check this out:

```
type SubType<Base, Condition> = Pick<Base, {
    [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never
}[keyof Base]>;
```

example usage for only keys of primitives:

```
type Primitive = boolean | number | bigint | string | symbol
type PrimitiveFieldKeys<T extends object> = keyof SubType<T, Primitive>;

const blah = {
  silly: "me",
  nested: {
    nestedSilly: "nestedMe",
  },
};

type BlahPrim = PrimitiveFieldKeys<typeof blah>;

const primitiveKeyOfBlah: BlahPrim = "silly";
```

credit to: https://medium.com/dailyjs/typescript-create-a-condition-based-subset-types-9d902cea5b8c

solved my problem :)